# patching Meteor default_connection

Tags: meteor, switch-statement, connection, default, ddp

I want to change the current default DDP connection, and reconnect another URL.

(this is for switching ELB port when it fails to use websocket like [this article](https://meteorhacks.com/load-balancing-your-meteor-app.html#aws-elastic-load-balancer-elbhttpawsamazoncomelasticloadbalancing).)

since I haven't found a proper way in the [documents](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html), I tried patching like

```
Meteor.connection = DDP.connect('new server url')
```

but it seemed to keep using the existing connection.

after trying several ways in the browser console and finally got something like working.

```
Meteor.disconnect();
Meteor.default_connection._stream.rawUrl = 'new server url';
Meteor.reconnect();
```

but I think it's a sort of hack since it is not documented.
do you know a better way to change default url?
when and what the `DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL` affects?

ps. I'm using Meteor 1.3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/d03b352bca91cfb6a2de039ad8ad38e90b3faabf/packages/ddp-client/stream_client_common.js#L136)

`Meteor.reconnect({ _forced: 1, url: 'new.url' });`

will reconnect to different Url.

Comment: Additionally, can add _sockjsOptions.protocols_whitelist to limit protocols.